# Use var as var name in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, var

I've a small question.
What I want to do is make a InnerHTML variable.

Maybe code explains it better, what I have now:

-----Javascript-----

```
var VarOne = 'Four';        
var VarTwo = 'Five';
var VarThree = 'Six';


function MyFunction(){
document.getElementById("MyDiv").innerHTML = ['Var' + event.target.id];
     }
```

---

-----Html-----

```
<div id="MyDiv"></div>
```

---

Instead of looking for a var, it gives as outcome 'VarOne, VarTwo, or VarThree, very logically, but how can I make it so he uses the var?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a string as a variable name directly, put your values into a hash:

```
var Vars = { 'One': 'Four', 'Two': 'Five', 'Three': 'Six' };        


function MyFunction(){
  document.getElementById("MyDiv").innerHTML = Vars[event.target.id];
}
```

Comment: +1 for using an object, as I completely forgot that `event.target` is a HTML element and its `id` usually isn't an integer.

Answer (score 4):

While Jonathan's answer is correct, you should avoid polluting the window object with variables.

Consider refactoring to use an object to store these values:

```
var values = {one:'four', two:'five', three:'six'};

function MyFunction(){
    document.getElementById("MyDiv").innerHTML = values[event.target.id];
}
```

This leaves only one variable in the window scope (which can also be avoided by using closures).

Answer (score 2):

Variables in the default scope are in the `window` object.  You should be able to do:

```
var id = 'One'
var VarOne = 'Four';
var VarTwo = 'Five';
var VarThree = 'Six';

alert(window["Var" + id]); // => Four
```

So you should just be able to change your `MyFunction` function's contents to be:

```
document.getElementById("MyDiv").innerHTML = window['Var' + event.target.id];
```

Answer (score 1):

A safer version and better-structured version might involve something like:

```
var DivContents = {
    VarOne : "Four",
    VarTwo : "Five",
    VarThree : "Six"
};


function MyFunction(){
    document.getElementById("MyDiv").innerHTML = DivContents['Var' + event.target.id];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, I'm no JavaScript expert, but maybe `eval()` will do what you want?

```
 var results = eval('Var' + number);
```

Alternatively, you could probably create an array and access your data that way.

Comment: +1, primarily because just because he suggested eval doesn't mean he should be downvoted by default. It's a very reasonable solution, especially if the variable isn't in the global scope.

Comment: Doesn't it kind of depend on where `number` is coming from?  If it's defined by the user, that seems like a flaw.

Comment: @Lusitanian: I don't know about this being a reasonable solution. Arranging the data so that it can be accessed without eval should be possible and not too much work in almost all cases. Unless you have something like a REPL, there should not be a need for eval.

Comment: There is actually a question here: "When is eval not evil": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil

Comment: @Thilo I do agree that it's not optimal, but it's possible that the questioner oversimplified the problem and he is, for some reason; forced to access the data this way. Regardless, I'd let him decide.